# compute a Means variable for a specific value in another variable

Tags: r, group-by, frame, mean

I would like to compute the mean age for every value from 1-7 in another variable called period.

This is how my data looks like:

```
work1 <- read.table(header=T, text="ID  dead    age gender  inclusion_year  diagnosis   surv    agrp    period
87  0   25  2   2006    1   2174    1   5
396 0   19  2   2003    1   3077    1   3
446 0   23  2   2003    1   3144    1   3
497 0   19  2   2011    1   268 1   7
522 1   57  2   1999    1   3407    2   1
714 0   58  2   2003    1   3041    2   3
741 0   27  2   2004    1   2587    1   4
767 0   18  1   2008    1   1104    1   6
786 0   36  1   2005    1   2887    3   4
810 0   25  1   1998    1   3783    4   2")
```

This is a subset of a data with more then 1500 observations

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
  sim <- read.table(header=T, text="Period  diagnosis   dead    surv    age
    1   1   50  50000   35.5
    2   1   80  70000   40.3
    3   1   100 80000   32.8
    4   1   120 100000  39.8
    5   1   140 1200000 28.7
    6   1   150 1400000 36.2
    7   1   160 1600000 37.1")
```

In this data set I would like to group by period and diagnosis while all deaths(dead) and surv(survival time in days) is summarised in period time. I would also like for a mean value of the age in every period.

Have tried everything, still can't create the data set I'm striving for.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Does `sim` corresponds to the provided data set? If not, please update it so the provided data set will match the desired output

Comment: It does not correspond to the provided data set. "Sim" is something i made in excel to provide u with an example of how i wanted it to look like.

Comment: This is not the correct practice. For future questions, please provide desired output that corresponds to the provided data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(work1)[, .(dead_sum=sum(dead),
                         surv_sum=sum(surv),
                         age_mean=mean(age)), keyby=.(period, diagnosis)]
```

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
work1 %>% group_by(period, diagnosis) %>%
  summarise(dead_sum=sum(dead), surv_sum=sum(surv), age_mean=mean(age))

# result
   period diagnosis dead_sum surv_sum age_mean
1:      1         1        1     3407 57.00000
2:      2         1        0     3783 25.00000
3:      3         1        0     9262 33.33333
4:      4         1        0     5474 31.50000
5:      5         1        0     2174 25.00000
6:      6         1        0     1104 18.00000
7:      7         1        0      268 19.00000
```

Comment: I think OP needs the cumulutive sum there so might want to add `Res[, c("dead", "surv") := lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = c("dead", "surv")]` (after saving the first operation in `Res`), though I find the question not entirely clear

Comment: Also, you can skip `order(period)` and use `keyby` instead of `key`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the `order` is unnecessary. Don't know where I thought I needed that. Probably affected by the hangover of X'mas drink  :-)

Comment: Ordering actually *is* necessary because `data.table` (unlike `aggregate` or `dplyr`) doesn't order via aggregation. I just meant that you can do the ordering using `keyby` instead of `order` (see my edit).

Comment: @DavidArenburg, See what you meant. Not thinking of it. :(

Comment: @Frank49, Sorry. Couldn't get your comment on gender.